# Wijmo wj-input-date not working if value = null

Tags: angular, typescript, masking, wijmo

I'm using wijmo input date for date masking with Angular2 and typescript

```
 <wj-input-date [value]="_note.StartDate" [format]="'d'" [mask]="'99/99/9999'" class="ibox1 rightalign"></wj-input-date>
```

It's working when I use it like this,

```
  constructor( ...
{
    if (this._note.StartDate != null) { this._note.StartDate = new Date(this._note.StartDate.toString()); }
    else { this._note.StartDate = new Date(); }
}
```

but, I don't want anything if value is null, like this

```
  constructor(...
{
    if (this._note.StartDate != null) { this._note.StartDate = new Date(this._note.StartDate.toString()); } 
}
```

but, it's giving exception "Assertion failed in Wijmo: Date expected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [required]="false" and remove [mask]="'99/99/9999'".
_note.StartDate should be Date type.

```
<wj-input-date [(value)]="_note.StartDate" [format]="'d'"  class="ibox1 rightalign" [required]="false"></wj-input-date>
```

Comment: There is a change in the latest version of the wijmo. It should be [isRequired]="false"